# Importing a module from PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

I am trying to import a python module from a particular directory on my system, but cannot get this working. Here is what I have tried:

1) Created a test file at `/home/karnivaurus/foo.py` which contains just the line `print('Hello world')`

2) Edited my `.bashrc` file to contain the line `PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$HOME"`

3) Tested this by opening a new terminal and running `echo $PYTHONPATH`, which prints out `":/home/karnivaurus"`

4) Started a python interpreter in the terminal by running `python`

5) Importing my test file by running `import foo`

However, this just returns the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named foo
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

I have tried printing `sys.path` from the interpreter, and it prints out a number of directories, but does not print out `/home/karnivaurus`. So it seems that `sys.path` is not being updated by `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 2):

Yo need to export PYTHONPATH in your .bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH
```

Exporting enables children processes to inherit the environment variable.